# Three dots appears in navigation icon iPhone when clicking the right bar button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

When I click on the right bar button three dots are being appeared on the right of left bar item that is navigation icon, Help me to remove these three dots and let me know why these dots appear even there is nothing alongside the navigation icon and there is no error in programming

[image]

Comment: have you added UIButton or UIBarButton ? if UIButton So check Button title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete button title as you've used image into the button. Button's width is not enough to show both image and title text all together. This is true for bar button also.

[image]